# How can I resize the windows work area, and then update the other windows to reflect the change please?

Tags: c#, winapi, resize, window

I have a toolbar application which changes the work area of the desktop and positions itself in the gap (either at the top or bottom of the screen). I need a function which will resize the other windows so that they are not left behind the toolbar after the resizing (the toolbar is always on top). I'm using the function below to change the work area:

```
private bool SetWorkspace(RECT rect)
        {
            bool result = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETWORKAREA,
                                      0,
                                      ref rect,
                                      SPIF_change);
            if (!result)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("The last error was: " +
                               Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString());
           }

          this.minAll();
          return result;
        }
```

and the minAll() function is how I'm resizing the other windows:

```
public void minAll(){
            IntPtr lHwnd = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", null);
            SendMessage(lHwnd, WM_COMMAND, (IntPtr)MIN_ALL, IntPtr.Zero);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            SendMessage(lHwnd, WM_COMMAND, (IntPtr)MIN_ALL_UNDO, IntPtr.Zero);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);              
         }
```

This method works, in that the workarea does get resized and no window keeps its old position outside it, but there are a few problems:

- Normal (ie. not maximised or minimized) windows are sometimes made so
  small that they aren't displayed, and have to be maximised from the
  taskbar (Vista) to be visible
- Sometimes the method makes other
  windows 'always on top' when they shouldn't be
- It changes the z-order of the windows, seemingly at random

The first two of these problems are fixed if you close and reopen the affected windows, but it's hardly an ideal solution and I can't even manually correct the z-order (I tried saving the z-order before the method and then restoring it afterwards, but no luck).

So, can anyone see what's wrong with how I'm doing this, or does anyone know how it's supposed to be done please?

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to do this is to create an AppBar. See `SHAppBarMessage`. There is a C++ sample [in the Knowledge Base](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/134206). There is a C# sample [on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/AppBar.aspx).